# How to Copy Value from one Input Field to Another

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have two input fields:

```
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" />
```

I want to make it so that whatever that's typed into id one will automatically be put into id two.

Any ideas on how to do this? Possibly javascript needed?

Comment: _"Possibly javascript needed?"_ Definitely JavaScript needed. Tried any?

Comment: No i haven't tried anything yet. I'm not even too sure how to start haha. I'm not the best with javascript :P

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply register an `input` even handler with the source `textfield` and copy the value to the target `textfield`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var src = document.getElementById("one"),
        dst = document.getElementById("two");
    src.addEventListener('input', function() {
        dst.value = src.value;
    });
};

// jQuery implementation

$(function () {
    var $src = $('#three'),
        $dst = $('#four');
    $src.on('input', function () {
        $dst.val($src.val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<strong> With vanilla JavaScript</strong>
<br />
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" />
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" />

<br />
<br />

<strong>With jQuery</strong>
<br />
<input type="text" id="three" name="three" />
<input type="text" id="four" name="four" />
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39gq804t/2/)

Comment: why jquery for this simple task?

Comment: Well regardless of whether it's far from the answer or not, it's just done the job for me. Simple and easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: Here is +1 for robbmj and -1 for Anuj Hari.

Comment: @Filip Haglund agreed that jQuery is not in the OPs question and an answer should have a JavaScript only implementation. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: P.S. You don't need keyup="mimic(this);"

Comment: ya I know. it was left over from earlier. Removed now.

Comment: I know that you know, but it will bring some confusion between young developers :) Now it's ok.

Answer (score -1):

```
    $( "#one" ).dblclick(function() {
         copyInputValue()
     });


    function copyInputValue() {

        let text1 = document.getElementById('two').value;        
        document.getElementById('one').value = text1;
         
    }
```

Comment: I am usually not against pure-code answers, but your answer uses functions from the jQuery library without explaining that the library needs to be loaded for your answer to work. Please add further explanation or remove it because it was flagged as low-quality.