# How Do I display user's input in different text areas?

Tags: javascript, html, copy

I'm trying to create a page similar to https://fonts.google.com/ where a user writes some in the search bar and the text is automatically displayed in different text areas with different fonts.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFh11.png)

how can i do this? Ive tried with this:

```
   <input type="text" id="textInput" name="txt" value="Search Fonts..." oninput="copyText()">
```

```
   <script>
    function copyText(){
        var text = document.getElementById("textInput");
        text.select();
        document.execCommand("copy")
        document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML=text.value;
    }
    </script>
```

However, the text isn't displayed in different areas, only in one, and its is copied too fast (Id like it does after user completely ends writes everything)

How can I improve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Copy Value from one Input Field to Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646465/how-to-copy-value-from-one-input-field-to-another)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<script>
function cloneText(textbox)
{
  document.getElementById('n2').value = textbox.value;
  document.getElementById('n3').value = textbox.value;
}

function copyText()
{
    let sorgent = document.getElementById("s1");
    let destination_1 = document.getElementById("d1");
    let destination_2 = document.getElementById("d2");
    destination_1.value = sorgent.value;
    destination_2.value = sorgent.value;
}


</script>

<h2>Copy In RealTime</h2>

<input type="text" name="n1" id="n1" onkeyup="cloneText(this)">
<input type="text" name="n2" id="n2"/>
<input type="text" name="n3" id="n3"/>

<h2>Copy With Button</h2>

<label>Sorgent</label><input type="text" name="s1" id="s1">
<label>Destination 1</label><input type="text" name="d1" id="d1"/>
<label>Destination 2</label><input type="text" name="d2" id="d2"/>

<input type="button" value="copy" onClick="copyText();" />
```